# How to turn off laptop native display with its lid open while using external monitors

Tags: windows, laptop, display, dell-inspiron

I'm using a Windows laptop (model: DELL inspiron-13-5379-2-in-1-laptop), and its LED lid has to be in open position, otherwise the laptop is designed not to repond when push power button to turn on.

I'm use the laptop mostly in a home-office setting connected to external monitors, and hope to turn off laptop's native display while keep the lid open.

Is it possible? and How? Hints will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not familiar with that model, but you should look in the BIOS to see if there is a setting you might be able to adjust.  You might want to check Power Settings and Additional Power Settings in Windows.  You might be able to set it so it won't go to sleep when plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an F key that can be used to toggle the various screen options. I have a different Dell laptop, and I use the F8 key together with the Fn (function). The symbol on my F8 key is that of a laptop with a screen behind it.

Comment: Thank you, @biff. I solved the issue now. Press Windows key  + P, or Fn + F8, then choose "Second screen only".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is true for all models, but many laptops use small magnetic sensors to know when the lid it closed.

Test: Using a paper-clip or other small ferrous object, see if you can fid where it 'sticks' round the screen edges.
Once located, you can place small magnet(s) on the opposite face & the computer will think the lid is closed.